# Strange bootstrap behavior with Chrome/Sierra

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, macos, font-awesome

With OSX Sierra, Chrome 57, Bootstrap 3.3.7, Font awesome 4.

The following :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> wait">Go</button>
```

And the Js part :

```
$('.btn').on("click", (evt) => {
  $('.btn').button("loading");
});
```

Does not work correctly. But It works with Safari !?

**Update :
It seems that fa-spin IS the problem !? Don't know why**

Any idea or workaround ?

Comment: I'm confused what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult give an appropiatte answer, because i dont know exactly what the error is, but as ideas or workarounds i'd give this:

Verify the font awesome 4 file. fa-spin is tricky sometimes, so use this CDN: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css, is the best choice to make it work!

Comment: But are you using that specific font? or the bootstrap's one?

Comment: Do you have another css' file that might be overwriting the mentioned one? May you show a screenshot with the error to know exactly how i it failing?

Comment: No just one CSS. Beside this, the same code works perfectly on windows and linux.